# SEHException in Word VSTO add-in (VS2010/Word2010)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, ms-word, vsto

I'm encountering a strange problem where my .net c# 4.0 Add-In (a relatively simple add-in with tons of interop and a customtaskpane) causes word to crash:

If the Add-in runs a longer time (>5min) sometimes suddenly the windows dialog "word does not work anymore" appears. After a few seconds, the ad-in error dialog opens and I got a glimpse on it showing an SEHException. But as Windows restarts Word immediatly, I'm not able to get a closer look on the exception. The debugger doesn't help, as it fails to break.

Any idea what causes an SEHException and what I can look into? Word/VSTO specific suggestion would be ideal but general suggestions about avoiding and investigating SEHExceptions are also welcome.

Thanks
chabun

Comment: When I run without the debugger I was able to catch the exception in the DispatcherUnhandledException event: The stack trace points to somewhere in the message pump and traces back to my ShowDialog call. The hresult is 0x80004005. Anyone an idea where I can look up HResults?

Comment: 0x80004005 is E_FAIL. Doesn't help either...

Answer (score 0):

One way you get this exception is if unmanaged code does an OS `RaiseException()` or causes a fault.  If that exception is propagated up the stack to managed code, we will try to map it to a managed exception.  For example, `STATUS_NO_MEMORY` maps to `OutOfMemoryException` and `STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION` maps to `NullReferenceException`.

For all the exception codes that don’t have a predefined mapping, we wrap them up into `SEHException`.

from [What is SEHException?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbrumme/archive/2003/04/15/51332.aspx) *cbrumme: msdn blogs*.

---

Try to add `try{} catch{}` block on every codes that are potentially cause `STATUS_NO_MEMORY` or `STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION` exception. Then use [`ExternalException.ErrorCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.externalexception.errorcode.aspx) to get exception details.

Comment: Yeah I read that. But what I really want to know what's the cause of the fault that raises the exception mapped to the SEHException. Anyone ever had that exception? And how did you fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the the exception never happens when compiled with **Release Configuration**.

If anyone should ever expirience the same, try the release config.

Comment: Just noticed that the exception happens not as often as before but still sometimes:(

Comment: What may help to know is that I'm periodically using a window in another thread to show status information (as the workload is done on the ui thread to make sure we're interacting correctly with word)

Comment: I was able to catch the exception another time. I'm now also using EXCEPTIon_POINTERS and Record to get more info: Exception code is: 0xE0000002 and the address is: 0x74F2B9BC

Comment: I now think I have isolated the exception. It's likely to be caused by the Shell Preview I'm using to display pdfs and other documents.